# Verify a method call within the tested class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Suppose I have the below interface.
And also assume `MethodA` calls `MethodB` like in the class below:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   public void MethodA();
   public void MethodB();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
   public void MethodA()
   {
      //some business logic

      //then call to MethodB
      if (somConditionMet)
      {  
         MethodB();
      }
   }

   public void MethodB()
   {
      //some other business logic
   }
}
```

And I'm writing a unit test to test `MethodA`.

```
[Test]
public MethodA_VerifyCallToMethodB()
{
   //Arrange

   //Act
   _sut.MethodA();
   
   //Assert
   // here I have to verify that MethodB is called in MethodA, how can I do it?
}
```

Is there a way to verify the call to `MethodB`? Because it's in the instantiated `_sut` object and not mocked, I can't use the `Verify` method.

Comment: "I can't use the Verify method" Yeap, and you shouldn't. If your methods depnd on one another so be it. Unless those methods are incredible huge and do a lot of things, in which case you should refactor them anyway into multiple classes, there should be no problem. In fact you implictely test B through A.

Comment: And just to be nitpicky: You do not test the interface - how would you? You test the implementation of it by `Foo`.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain `In fact you implictely test B through A.` Indeed. I hoped for a possibility to verify it using a simple `Moq` functionality. I just want to test the behaviour `if (somConditionMet)` in `MethodA`, and at that point, I don't want to dive into `MethodB`

Comment: _" I just want to test the behaviour if (somConditionMet) in MethodA"_ - **if** in that case the execution of `MethodB` has sideeffects, you _could_ assert those happened ...

Comment: you could make `B` virtual and create a class deriving from your SuT. So basically you mock your SuT yourself. However that breaks the idea of "what is a unit" some way, doesn't it?

Comment: @Fildor currently I'm doing it that way. But as I said, I hoped for solution without diving into `MethodB`

Comment: But _are_ you really diving into "MethodB"? A different implementation may fulfill the contract of interface `MethodA` without calling `MethodB`. Should the test then fail?

Comment: Since `MethodA` is void, is must cause some kind of side effect.  Test that whatever side effect that is supposed to have happened after calling `MethodA` has run successfully took place.  Whether it used `MethodB` or some other means of accomplishing it's desired result is irrelevant to you when testing it.  Verify that it did what it needed to, don't test that it did it in the way that you think it should have.  That just boxes you in later when you want to change implementation details and now all of your tests break despite the behavior still being correct.